# pytorch loss.backward() keeps running for hours

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I am using pytorch to train some x-ray images but I ran into the following issue:

in the line : `loss.backward()`, the program just keeps running and never end, and there is no error or warning.

```
            loss, outputs = self.forward(images, targets)  
            loss = loss / self.accumulation_steps
            print("loss calculated: " + str(loss))

            if phase == "train":
                print("running loss backwarding!") 
                loss.backward()
                print("loss is backwarded!")
                if (itr + 1 ) % self.accumulation_steps == 0:
                    self.optimizer.step()
                    self.optimizer.zero_grad()
```

The loss calculated before this is something like `tensor(0.8598, grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)`.

Could anyone help me with why this keeps running or any good ways to debug the backward() function?

I am using torch 1.2.0+cu92 with the compatible cuda 10.0.

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give a definite answer but I have a guess.

Your code looks fine but from the output you've posted (`tensor(0.8598, grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)`) I conclude that you are operating on your CPU and not on the GPU.

One possible explanation is that the backwards pass is **not running forever, but just takes very very long**. Training a large network on a CPU is much slower than on a GPU. **Check your CPU and memory utilization**. It might be that your data and model is too big to fit into your main memory, forcing the operation system to use your hard disk, which would slow down execution by several additional magnitudes. If this is the case I generally recommend:

- Use a smaller batch size.
- Downscale your images (if possible).
- Only open images that are currently needed.
- Reduce the size of your model.
- Use your GPU (if available) by calling `model.cuda(); images = images.cuda()` before starting your training.

If that doesn't solve your problem you could start narrowing down the issue by doing some of the following:

- Create a minimal working example to reproduce the issue.
- Check if the problem persists with other, very simple model architectures.
- Check if the problem persists with different input data
- Check if the problem persists with a different PyTorch version

Comment: thank you. I found the solution by upgrading my pyspark to the latest version and then it worked!!!